# Why the <path> in a SVG can't be applied $.show() animation on Safari(iOS+MacOS)?

Tags: svg, safari

Here is the link. In the demo, there is a Japan map and I want to play an animation to turn every province in Japan to red. It works well in Chrome. But failed in Safari.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/376071/

Here is the full code:

```
// SVG graphics
var svg_html = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="330px" height="245px" viewBox="0 0 666 494"><defs><g id="BHD_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 154 -8.8L 58.7 -76 35 7.6 -0.5 31 18.5 68 48 70 45 44 103 75 135.5 33.5 178 30.4 185 -21 154 -9 Z"></path></g><g id="QS_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 66.5 41.5L 54.4 0 41.7 9 26 9 16.5 2.3 0 33 66.5 41.5 Z"></path></g><g id="QT_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 8 22.4L 0 41 40 51 52 4.6 15.4 0 10.6 9 3.7 12.3 8 22.4 Z"></path></g><g id="YS_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 12 0L 0 47 34.5 52.3 41 3.6 12 0 Z"></path></g><g id="SX_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 21 31.7Q 30.3 36 40.4 38.6L 64 10 23.7 0 0 20Q 5.3 23.6 11 26.6 16 29.3 21 31.7 Z"></path></g><g id="GC_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 23.7 0L 0 28.6 38 38.7 58.3 5.5 23.7 0 Z"></path></g><g id="XX_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 64.6 13.2L 44.3 0 1 39 0 44.4 30.4 49.3 58.4 31 64.6 13 Z"></path></g><g id="FD_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 60.3 38.2L 65.5 16 5.7 0 0 17 60.3 38 Z"></path></g><g id="LM_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 18.5 0L 0 23.3 28 34.4 33.4 5 18.5 0 Z"></path></g><g id="CC_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 0 29.3L 18.7 37 25.7 7 5.6 0 0 29.3 Z"></path></g><g id="QYU_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 52.7 30.3L 52 11.2Q 42.4 7.3 32.3 5 17 1.7 1.4 0L 0 13.4 17 26.6 52.7 30.3 Z"></path></g><g id="DJ_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 41.5 19.2L 43.7 3.6 8.3 0 0 12.4 41.5 19 Z"></path></g><g id="QY_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 12 22.7L 5.5 40 15 50 35.3 14 0 0 0.5 18.6 12 22.7 Z"></path></g><g id="FS_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 33.7 0.9L 13 0 0 26.3 29 31.4 33.7 1 Z"></path></g><g id="SC_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 24 1.7L 0 38 20 48.5 33 21 47 0 24 1.7 Z"></path></g><g id="CY_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 43.5 29.7L 46 4.7 16.5 0 12.6 25 0 38.6Q 0.4 41.4 1.4 46.6 1.7 48 2 49 2.4 51.7 2.5 52 2.6 52.5 6 59.2L 15 53.6 19 38.5 43.5 29.7 Z"></path></g><g id="SL_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 40.5 16.6Q 42.7 13.6 43 12.7L 26.7 0 3.6 8 0 21 24.7 36.7Q 36 22.5 40.5 16.6 Z"></path></g><g id="SNC_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 51.6 24L 51.5 7 8.3 0 0 9Q 9 14.6 19 17.6 35 22 51.6 24 Z"></path></g><g id="JG_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 9 0L 0 5 2 22 15 30.5 30.5 28.4Q 31 28.4 35.4 39.7 39.4 50 42 58.2L 47 56.7 54.5 27 9 0 Z"></path></g><g id="AZ_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 37 8.8Q 37 9 32.7 0L 0 11.3 6 29.3 38 22Q 38 20.3 37.3 14.3L 37 9 Z"></path></g><g id="QF_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 18.3 0L 0 14 5.6 41 38 29.5 36 17 47.4 5 18.3 0 Z"></path></g><g id="SCH_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 27.6 0L 2.4 33 0 53.6 15.3 55 38 31 27.6 0 Z"></path></g><g id="HGS_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 40.5 39L 51.3 28.6 53.5 8.5 8 0 0 12 40.5 39 Z"></path></g><g id="NL_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 0 29.7L 21 33.6 34 16.5 20 0 6.6 0 0 29.7 Z"></path></g><g id="DB_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 28 10.4L 10 0 0 36.4 21.4 40.3 28 10.4 Z"></path></g><g id="JD_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 0 34.2L 19.3 45.5 32 45 23 0 2 2.6 0 34 Z"></path></g><g id="BK_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 32.6 2.4L 9 0 0 34 31 33.3 32.6 2.4 Z"></path></g><g id="NQ_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 50.6 21.9L 55 5.4 2.3 0 0 17 50.6 22 Z"></path></g><g id="WS_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 45 19.5L 49.3 4.6 0 0 6.4 20.3 45 19.5 Z"></path></g><g id="DG_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 63 20.8L 65 3.3 33.3 0 0 19.4 13.7 34 63 21 Z"></path></g><g id="GD_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 53.5 20.4L 47 0 0 12.6 13 26 53.5 20.4 Z"></path></g><g id="SK_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 43 35.8L 63.3 29.4 35 0Q 25 9 23.3 10 14 17 0 23.4L 43 36 Z"></path></g><g id="AY_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 48 18.4L 41 0 10.3 0.3 0 22.5 48 18.4 Z"></path></g><g id="XC_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 33.5 0L 0 8.7 7.3 27.3 45.5 23.5 33.5 0 Z"></path></g><g id="GZ_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 53 17.7L 49 0 0 4 11 29.4 28 18.7 44 21.4 53 17.7 Z"></path></g><g id="DD_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 4 21.2L 35 23 38 0 0 4 4 21 Z"></path></g><g id="FG_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 15.3 0L 0 9.4 3 38.4 17.7 33.3 43.3 12 15.3 0 Z"></path></g><g id="DF_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 22.4 0L 0 20.7Q 6.3 24.5 12.7 28.4 12.7 28.4 13 28.5 25.4 34.3 38 40.2L 40.5 20.3 22.4 0 Z"></path></g><g id="GQ_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 18 0L 0 31 13.5 49 42.5 11 18 0 Z"></path></g><g id="LED_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 27 0L 7 0 0 34 25 52 46 25 27 0 Z"></path></g><g id="XB_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 16 4Q 6.6 7 5 7.8L 0 33 20.3 33 24.7 38 42 8 29.5 0Q 25 1 16 4 Z"></path></g><g id="CQ_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 21 0L 0 18 23 33.3 46.7 13 21 0 Z"></path></g><g id="CS_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 101 46.7L 113 18 82.5 34.7 54 26 54 43 31.4 56.7 22 87.5 54.5 76.6 54 60 101 46.7 Z"></path></g><g id="QM_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 1 17.9L 0 27.3 30.6 30.7 49.3 7.3 28.6 0 1 18 Z"></path></g><g id="FJ_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 25 0L 0 11 4.4 33 27.3 24.4 45 10.5 25 0 Z"></path></g><g id="ZUOH_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 37 0L 8 9 0 21 26.4 34.5 39 29.3 37 0 Z"></path></g><g id="ZH_pid"><path fill="#699" stroke="none" d="M 1 13.2Q 2.3 22 4.3 31 4.4 31 4.6 31.4 11 39.4 18 47.3L 29 33 22 0 0.3 8Q -0 8.3 0 8.5 0.3 11 1 13 Z"></path></g><path id="L001S" stroke="#aaa" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="M 453 483.4L 530 406.4 631 406.4"></path></defs><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,479.3,78)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#BHD_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,484.5,154)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#QS_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,467.5,190)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#QT_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,510.6,195)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#YS_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,442,233.8)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#SX_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,485.6,244.6)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#GC_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,395.4,256)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#XX_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,457,270.4)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#FD_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,460.3,298)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#LM_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,491,304.4)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#CC_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,424.9,320.2)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#QYU_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,433.9,349.9)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#DJ_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,480.2,332.6)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#QY_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,359.4,294.9)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#FS_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,336.7,271.8)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#SC_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,378.4,303.4)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#CY_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,396.3,335.9)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#SL_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,423.7,365)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#SNC_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,385.5,360.3)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#JG_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,345.7,356.6)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#AZ_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,339.3,323.9)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#QF_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,317.3,375)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#SCH_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,263,400.6)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#HGS_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,296.6,372.6)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#NL_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,272.2,361.4)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#DB_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,283,324)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#JD_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,249.2,324.3)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#BK_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200,318.5)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#NQ_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200.6,338.7)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#WS_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,134.2,314.9)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#DG_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,150.4,338.8)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#GD_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,96.6,336)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#SK_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,152,379.5)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#AY_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,195.8,370.3)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#XC_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,151.7,400.8)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#GZ_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,204,396.7)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#DD_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,64.2,363.7)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#FG_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,86.4,378.5)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#DF_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,81,410.2)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#GQ_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,46.4,436.7)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#LED_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,54.2,401)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#XB_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,2,396.9)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#CQ_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,487.4,400.2)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#CS_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,426.6,289.8)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#QM_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,309.2,312)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#FJ_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,25.2,373.8)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#ZUOH_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,314.4,339.3)"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#ZH_pid"></use></g></g><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><use xlink:href="#L001S"></use></g></svg>';

// related object
var g = '{"BHD__t":35,"BHD":0,"QS__t":10,"QS":0,"YS__t":13,"YS":0,"QT__t":13,"QT":0,"GC__t":14,"GC":0,"SX__t":13,"SX":0,"FD__t":12,"FD":0,"CC__t":31,"CC":0,"LM__t":15,"LM":0,"QM__t":11,"QM":0,"DJ__t":53,"DJ":0,"QYU__t":39,"QYU":0,"QY__t":35,"QY":0,"SNC__t":19,"SNC":0,"XX__t":19,"XX":0,"FS__t":10,"FS":0,"SC__t":10,"SC":0,"FJ__t":8,"FJ":0,"SL__t":13,"SL":0,"CY__t":19,"CY":0,"QF__t":21,"QF":0,"JG__t":23,"JG":0,"AZ__t":33,"AZ":0,"SCH__t":14,"SCH":0,"ZH__t":13,"ZH":0,"JD__t":14,"JD":0,"BK__t":29,"BK":0,"NL__t":12,"NL":0,"DB__t":33,"DB":0,"HGS__t":8,"HGS":0,"NQ__t":4,"NQ":0,"DG__t":8,"DG":0,"WS__t":14,"WS":0,"GD__t":14,"GD":0,"SK__t":13,"SK":0,"DD__t":8,"DD":0,"XC__t":8,"XC":0,"AY__t":11,"AY":0,"GZ__t":11,"GZ":0,"FG__t":30,"FG":0,"ZUOH__t":9,"ZUOH":0,"CQ__t":13,"CQ":0,"XB__t":15,"XB":0,"DF__t":13,"DF":0,"GQ__t":9,"GQ":0,"LED__t":15,"LED":0,"CS__t":11,"CS":0}';

// a counter to check whether it's done.
window.count = 0;

// createa a HTML Element
var $svg = $(svg_html);

// the array to store inside element ("path")
var arr = [];
$svg.find('g').each(function(){
  var t_id = $(this).attr('id');
  if(t_id && t_id.includes('_pid')){ 
    $(this).children('path').attr('fill', '#fff');
    arr.push($(this));
  }
});

// Get the object form from a compressed string
var global_city_data = JSON.parse(g);

// Play the animation
function setProvinceColor(id) {
  var $p = arr[id];
  var province_id = $p.attr('id').split('_pid')[0];

  var $path = $p.find('path');

  // First, change its color to the wanted one
  $path.attr('fill', '#f00');
  // Then, hide it
  $path.hide();
  // Last, play an animation to show it
  $path.show(500);

  if(window.count >= arr.length - 1){
    console.log('done!');
    return;
  }
  window.count++;

  // Set this to make the animation more and more faster
  var time_index = 700;

  setTimeout(function(){
    setProvinceColor(window.count);
  }, time_index/window.count);
}
// Start
setProvinceColor(0, false);
// Add the SVG to HTML
$('#svg_holder').empty().append($svg);
```

The code is above. The animation can be played quite well as expected on desktop chrome.

But it's not working in Safari. Both iOS and MacOS would fail to play the animation.

I think it's quite simple and really don't know how to fix it. Is there anything I can do?

BTW:

1. The reason I didn't upload the code here is that the SVG is too long and it would mess the editor. I guess it's a bug
2. The SVG code is output via the latest version of Adobe Animate.

Thanks,

Comment: I kind of suggested it in my answer but ill note here, the reason your SVG is so big is because the markup is quite poor. You don't need so many groups, definitions, ids etc. All this extra stuff just makes for a heap of SVG markup that is harder to process.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problems stem from your use of use / xlink:href.
If you change your code to target the `<use>` elements rather than the definition `<paths>`:

```
var arr = [];
$svg.find('use').each(function(){
  var t_id = $(this).attr('xlink:href');
  if(t_id && t_id.includes('_pid')){ 
    $(this).attr('fill', '#fff');
    arr.push($(this));
  }
});
//...

function setProvinceColor(id) {
  var $p = arr[id];

  // First, change its color to the wanted one
  $p.attr('fill', '#f00');
  // Then, hide it
  $p.hide();
  // Last, play an animation to show it
  $p.show(500);
  //...
}
```

It will mostly work, however you'll have to remove the `fill="#699"` from the `<path>`s under `<defs>`, this will allow the fill applied to the `<use>` in jQuery to take precedence.

Heres the fiddle demonstrating the above: https://jsfiddle.net/nm1ofxd2/#&togetherjs=1CmxN4cIaV

This behaviour might seem odd but remember that the original `<path>`s are just definitions that are bing implemented by the `<use>` elements later. 
Depending on the renderer certain changes to the definition might not be propagated to the reference.

I recommend avoiding `<defs>` and `<use>` altogether unless you're specifically using them for instancing, and even then I would advise to avoid styling your definition paths.